# How to stop getline() loop over cin automatically

Tags: c++, cin, getline

Hello my code is the following:

```
while (getline(cin, line))
{
    // process on line
}
```

so this causes the user to keep putting lines until he inputs ^z.
How can I make it so that it automatically stops without user intervention? For example, when the user pastes the input lines without ^z, I need the above loop to do the processing and then stop.

Comment: *all the user has to do is paste the input lines and it will automatically work*. How do you expect to be able to tell the program that the user is "done"? Without a clear signal (be it end-of-file, empty line etc) the program has no way of knowing whether the user is going to type another line or is in fact "done".

Comment: It honestly sounds like you're asking for magic. Is there some rule that permits the program to identify the end of the output? If so, implement that rule. If not, obviously it can't be done.

Comment: What if the user pastes lines, then afterwards wants to do paste some more lines or type some things in manually?

Comment: I'm not asking for magic that's what the school solution does:
it runs the program and pasting the input automatically prints the result.

Answer (score 1):

`std::getline` will extract until:

- EOF was encountered, which sets eofbit
- A delimiter was encountered (no flag is set, so the next extraction won't fail)
- You encountered `std::string::max_size`, which sets failbit
- An error occurred

You can't have the user copy/paste and expect the program to automatically know that the user is done. What if the input was something else, like a file?

RE comment: you can still pipe input from a file and the program can't tell the difference.

```
# will stop extraction via EOF
cat file | ./a.out
```

Comment: input can't be a file because they requested that the program takes input via cin.